# Cursor Input to PostgreSQL function/stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can we have Cursor Input to PostgreSQL function/stored procedure.

I am having an Oracle Package to be converted to Postgres Equivalent, which is having a cursor declared in it and it is used as input to multiple procedures in it. What is the best way to convert it to equivalent in PostgreSQL.

ORACLE PACKAGE CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BCP01."CDA_CRL_PKG" AS

   -- Declare cursor output variables types
TYPE crl_list_cur IS REF CURSOR;

PROCEDURE get_crl_list_sp
(
get_crl_list_inout
IN OUT crl_list_cur,
primary_content_id_in
IN cms_related_content.primary_content_id%TYPE,
status_out 
OUT VARCHAR2
);


END CDA_crl_pkg;
;​
```

Comment: I don't think there is a direct equivalent, but did you try passing a `refcursor`?  You will need to provide a lot more information by describing the actual, underlying problem you are trying to solve with that approach (and no, "I want to migrate from Oracle to Postgres, is **not** the underlying problem). But it also sounds like a strange thing to do in Oracle. How can you pass a single cursor to multiple procedures? After the first call the cursor is probably closed/exhausted. So what can the next procedures do with it?

Comment: I am migrating oracle Package to equivalent in PostgreSQL

Comment: Unfortunately the Postgres equivalent to an Oracle package ***does not exist***. About the closest you will get is to create a schema with the package name then each procedure and function becomes an independent procedure of function and any package level become rows on a parameters table.  That will get the majority, of course references to package variables become  selects from the parameter table.   As@a_horse_with_no_name indicated you need to describe the problem the Oracle package solves.